# How to apply a function on a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apply

I wrote a function to determine the weekday. When I try to apply it to my data frame face the following error.

```
data['date'].head() 

0    2016-01-01
1    2016-01-01
2    2016-01-01
3    2016-01-01
4    2016-01-01

def weekday_determination(col):
    year, month, day = (int(x) for x in col.split('-'))
    ans = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    return ans.strftime('%A')

data['week_day'] = data['date'].apply(weekday_determination, axis=1)
```

I face the following error:

> TypeError: weekday_determination() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Comment: `data['date'].apply(weekday_determination)` works for me, without the `axis=1`

Comment: how is it possible as we do not have any index named 'date'?
Furthermore, I need to apply for the whole column, this is why I add  'axis =1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is better use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`Series.dt.day_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html):

```
data['week_day'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date']).dt.day_name()

print (data)
         date week_day
0  2016-01-01   Friday
1  2016-01-01   Friday
2  2016-01-01   Friday
3  2016-01-01   Friday
4  2016-01-01   Friday
```

In your solution is used [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html), so no parameter `axis`:

```
data['date'] = data['date'].apply(weekday_determination)
```

Possible solution with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
data['week_day'] = data.apply(lambda x: weekday_determination(x['date']), axis=1)
```